# Extending $L$ with constants of natural rank

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

I am stuck trying to understand part of the proof of Lemma 6.7 in Manin's *Logic for Mathematicians*. I am aware that notation may vary and parts of the question may rely on definitions made earlier in the book, but I would be grateful for any insight.

Here $\cal{E}$ consists of a set of consistent formulas of a language $L$, and $\cal{E}$ contains Ax$L=\{\text{tautologies of $L$}\}\cup\{\text{quantifier axioms}\}$.

The language $L'$ is obtained from $L$ by adding a new set of constants whose cardinality is that of the alphabet of $L+\aleph_0$.

We first show that $\cal{E} \cup \rm{Ax} L' $ must be consistent, after which comes the following paragraph:

> We consider the set $S$ of formulas $P(x)$ containing one free variable $x$ and such that $\neg\forall x P(x) ∈ \cal{E} \cup \rm{Ax} L' $. For each $P(x)$ in $S$ we choose a new
> constant $c_P$ subject to the following restriction: each $c_P$ can be assigned a natural number, its rank, in such a way that if a constant of rank $n$ occurs in $P(x)$ then $c_P$ has rank $>n$. This can be done since card$(S)\le$ card(alphabet of $L') = $ card(alphabet of $L) + \aleph_0$ .

This doesn't make sense to me, so I think I probably misunderstand something important.

Do the constants $c_P$ come from $L'$ or can some of them come from $L$? Can the same constant be chosen for different formulas $P_1(x), P_2(x)$?

I don't see how to assign ranks to each constant, especially if $S$ is uncountable.

Comment: I've made a correction, I saw that I accidentally wrote $L'$ instead if $L$. Actually, that's what I said in words, constants are not in the original language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall outline what is basically going on in the way I am familiar with, because, I suppose, once the main idea has been grasped, the rest could be worked out according to the specific details of a particular exposition.

Our intention is to build an increasing sequence of consistent set of sentences in an expanded language $\mathcal{L'}$ based on the original language $\mathcal{L}$ of cardinality $\lvert\lvert\mathcal{L}\rvert\rvert$:

$$T=T_{0}\subset T_{1}\subset\ldots\subset T_{n}\subset\ldots$$

where $n<\lvert\lvert\mathcal{L}\rvert\rvert$ and $T$ is a consistent set of sentences of $\mathcal{L}$.

We form a set of constants $\mathcal{C}$ such that, for each $j<\lvert\lvert\mathcal{L}\rvert\rvert$, $c_{j}\in\mathcal{C}$ is a constant symbol that does not occur in $\mathcal{L}$ and $c_{j}\neq c_{k}$, whenever $k<j<\lvert\lvert\mathcal{L}\rvert\rvert$. **Notice that this condition is provided by the notion of “rank” in the cited text.** Hence,
$$\mathcal{C}=\{c_{j}\,\vert\,j<\lvert\lvert\mathcal{L}\rvert\rvert\}$$

$\mathcal{L}$ is expanded to $\mathcal{L'}$ by $\mathcal{C}$

$$\mathcal{L'}=\mathcal{L}\cup\mathcal{C}$$

Next, we list all formulas of $\mathcal{L'}$ with just one free variable for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ as

$$\phi_{0}(x_{0}), \phi_{1}(x_{1}),\ldots, \phi_{n}(x_{n}),\ldots$$

Then, we define $T_{n}$ of $\mathcal{L'}$ for each $n$ as follows:

We set $$T_{0} = T$$

To define $T_{1}$, we take $c_{0}$ as the first constant not appearing in $\phi_{0}(x_{0})$ and $θ_{0}$ as $\exists x_{0}\phi_{0}(x_{0})\rightarrow\phi_{0}(c_{0}/x_{0})$ in which $\phi_{0}(c_{0}/x_{0})$ is the uniform substitution of $c_{0}$ for $x_{0}$. Usually, $c_{0}$ is called *witness* to $T_{0}$ —a remarkably descriptive name. Notice that this is an alternative formulation of what Manin gives on p. 57 as

> $$RP: \neg\forall x P(x)\Rightarrow\neg P(c_{P})$$ belongs to
> $\cal{E}$.
>
> The intuitive meaning of $RP$ is; “If not all $x$ have the property
> $P$, then some concrete object $c_{P}$ can be found that does not have
> this property.”

Thus

$$T_{1} = T_{0}\cup{\theta_{0}}$$

and so on for the rest of the sequence.

Hopefully, the answers to the questions have been fairly clarified by now:

> Do the constants $c_P$ come from $L'$ or can some of them come from
> $L$?

The constants should not be $L$-terms, otherwise our endeavour would be meaningless.

> Can the same constant be chosen for different formulas $P_1(x), P_2(x)$?

See that in the described method of extension, for each formula $P(x)$, a new constant (i.e., witness) is assigned.

> I don't see how to assign ranks to each constant, especially if $S$ is
> uncountable.

“Rank” is explicated above; it is an ordinary indexing. Therefore, it cannot be uncountable, for we enumerate the formulas by it.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. How does one justify that we can list all formulas of $\cal{L}'$ with one free variable? I'm guessing that if there are countably many symbols in $\cal{L}'$, because each formula is of finite length there can only be countably many formulas? 
I'm not sure if I can assume that $||\cal{L}' ||$ is countable, is it justified?

Comment: Whether a limit ordinal or not, the cardinality is standardly, but not necessarily, countable. You may wish to take a look at my answers https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4423202/754923 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4500729/754923 and contrast them to [infinitary logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/).